# AlertDialog doesn't appear, why?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Ok i want to show this AlertDialog but i only get a blank space without a message or buttons. Does someone know what's going wrong? This is my main class including the dialog:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
public void CreateDialog1(View view){
final DialogFragment DFragment1=new DialogFragment();
    DFragment1.show(getFragmentManager(), "Alarm1");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplication());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.create_alarm1);

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         Intent intent1 = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)
                .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "You have set an alarm for the first hour at 6:30 AM")
                .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 6)
                .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 30);
}


 if (intent1.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent1);
                DFragment1.dismiss();
            }
        }

    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            DFragment1.getDialog().cancel();

        }
    });AlertDialog dialog1=builder.create();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to show it after build, add:

```
dialog1.show();
```

Comment: Is there also something else what could be wrong? If i add that code my app crashes and the blank space also doesn't appear anymore.....

Comment: @SanderM2001 please post some error log so that at least I have some clue to start debugging.

Comment: O, it's fine already. I made some mistake in code which i thought wasn't helpful to post.... @xwhyLikeThis  Thanks for your help!